# Eclipse crash with error JVM terminated. Exit code=11

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, java

Eclipse crashes on Ubuntu 14.04 after throwing below error message.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=11
/usr/bin/java
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata ea0009
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

**Eclipse version : 3.8.1**

**eclipse.ini**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

**workspace/.metadata/.log**

```
!SESSION 2016-01-29 16:32:26.126 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.8.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2016-01-29 16:37:51.223
!MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
!SESSION 2016-01-29 16:39:42.541 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.8.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2016-01-29 16:39:44.621
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2016-01-29 16:42:30.180
!MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
```

I am using oracle java version "1.8.0_72" as below.

```
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

I have also tried with open jdk and same problem occurred.

Any solution or workaround to avoid this crash ?

Comment: This is not the error message. It's your startup configuration (usually set through an ini file near eclipse executable). You should find a JVM dump file near you eclipse executable file, or on you current working directory.

Comment: Maybe you have only a JRE installed instead of a JDK. What is the output of `/usr/bin/javac -version`?

Comment: Your jre is 32bit or 64 bit? you have to run 32bit eclipse with 32bit jvm, 64bit eclipse with 64bit jvm

Comment: @SubOptimal JDK is not mandatory to run eclipse, JRE is enough.

Comment: @SubOptimal output is : javac 1.8.0_72

Comment: @SumitSingh my ubuntu is 64 bit & also jdk is also 64 bit as in edited question. I have installed eclipse from Ubuntu software center.

Comment: @SumitSingh Agree with you. Always assume people want to code Java with Eclipse. ;-)

Comment: @Priyank Could you please start Eclipse from a console. To see if during startup there might be some other errors displayed.

Comment: You need to post the full errormessage you get. If you can find it, run eclipse with `-XX:ErrorFile` param.

Comment: @Priyank **1)** Have you started Eclipse from terminal? **2)** What value has your environment variable `JAVA_HOME`? **3)** How do you start Eclipse?

Comment: @SubOptimal I have tried to open eclipse with both way.

Comment: @Priyank Have you tried replacing jdk version 1.8.0_72 with 1.8.0_66?

Comment: Did you try to install as **root** user?

Answer (score 2):

from default eclipse-inst.ini‘s  GTK section

```
Eclipse Installer
-data
@noDefault
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

to

```
Eclipse Installer
-data
@noDefault
--launcher.GTK_version
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on whatever packaging and version of Eclipse that Ubuntu has provided, it is usually recommended to download Eclipse [directly from the source](https://eclipse.org/downloads/). It's also a good idea to specify the full path to your JVM in the `eclipse.ini` file, [as described in the wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to install webup8team's java via ppa. It will pick the correct one jdk/jre and so on:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
4. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default

I hope after this the problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Add the jdk version in your eclipse.ini file,

-vm
 "path_to_your_jvm"

Answer (score -1):

Have a look into the Eclipse logfile

```
${location of the workspace}/.metadata/.log
```

Comment: There is no -vm parameter in eclipse.ini file. I have added eclipse.ini in question.

Comment: How has downvoted the answer? If you check the history of the question you will see the the output of `workspace/.metadata/.log from 2016-01-29 16:32:26.126` was added after my answer. And the advise to have a look into the log file to check if there is some additional information is not wrong. Isn't it?